# spring boot - returning pojo response from filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-filter

i want to create a filter/bean that have autowired constructor parameters and for every request to some urls checks the header and returns a pojo error (or ideally throws the exception that will be handled by spring), or passes the request through the filter chain. something like

```
@Bean
class MyFilter {

  @Autowired
  public MyFilter(MyService myService) {...}

  public doFilter(request, response, chain) {
     if (request. ...) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        // or return new MyErrorPojo()
     }
     return chain.doFilter(request, response)
  }
}
```

what's the spring's way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336154/spring-filter-send-different-enum-object-per-url-mapping

Comment: nope, i want a single filter that verifies a header. if header is not present i want to return nice json error (pojo or exception handled by spring)

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans

Comment: but it says nothing about returning pojo or exceptions. it's just a way of registering filters and autowiring

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order( 1 )
public class RequestFilter implements Filter
{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException

    {

        HttpServletRequest req = ( HttpServletRequest ) request;
        if( false )
        {
            response.getWriter().println( "error" );
            throw new ServletException( "" );
        }
        else
        {
            doFilter( request, response, chain );
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here you have a rather confusing mix of technologies:

Filters belong to servlet specification and operate at the HTTP request level of abstraction.

Once the filter chain passes and comes to DispatcherServlet (an entry point to spring mvc) spring comes into play with all the MVC goodies.

So if you want to check the header there is an abstraction called `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter`

You can basically create a class that implements this interface, and check the header in the method: that belongs to this interface

`public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)`

As you see, you have an access to the request and its possible to check the headers there.

Now I haven't used it by myself (can't check right now) but it requires the configuration at the level of WebMvcConfigurer that has a special "addInterceptor" method. So I can't confirm that just adding a bean of the created type is enough or you whould configure it with WebMvcConfigurer